# Changed Biber/Biblatex citation styles, changed back, now citation keys instead of citations are displayed

Tags: biblatex, citing, biber, apa-style

I am attempting to create an APA citation of the format (Rubinstein, 1994, p. 773).

The instructions I found online say to use:

```
\parencite[p.~773]{Rubinstein1994},
```

with the following set-up:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,natbib=true]{biblatex}
```

It sort of worked, but then I changed the style to `apa`, then `apalike` and then back again to `authoryear` which seems to have wrecked something since now my citations only show up as (Rubinstein1985) which is the citation key, not the citation.

I use TeXpad and have typeset multiple times. Any hints are much appreciated!

Comment: what happens if you delete the `.aux` and `.bbl` and retry the compiling process?

Comment: No change, unfortunately. What I did was enable hidden files and then deleted them from the .texpad.tmp folder.

Comment: Welcome! I'm pretty sure this is off-topic because TeXpad doesn't use TeX.

Comment: Or is that only when used with iOS? I'm confused. Some of the other questions suggest you use it with MacTeX. Others that it is standalone and has a built in compiler.

Comment: Note that with `biblatex` you can leave out the page prefix `p.~` and just go with `\parencite[773]{Rubinstein1994}` the suitable prefix will be inserted automatically. If it worked before, it should work again if you just delete the temporary files (`.aux`, `.bbl`, `.bcf`) and try again. Note that `apalike` is not a style known to `biblatex`, so it will cause an error.

Comment: Any news here? From what we know so far we can't say much, except that it should work (especially if it did before) at least after you got rid of the temporary files.

Comment: I changed the backend to bibtex and it worked. I had tried that before and typset a bunch of times, why it did not work then but worked now ist beyond me. Anyways, thank you!

Comment: Do you want to write a self-answer, or do you have any other suggestion what we could do to mark your question as solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the backend to bibtex and it worked. I had tried that before and typset a bunch of times, why it did not work then but worked now ist beyond me.